# Matrix multiplication with MPI using serial algorithm and another one using parallel version

Tags: c#, .net, mpi, matrix-multiplication

The program multiply two matrices using the MPI.
The have two methods to calculate the matrix product: one using serial algorithm and another one using parallel version.
but the methods are returning different Matrices result. can anyone help me

```
using System;
using MPI;

class MatrixMultiplication
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (new MPI.Environment(ref args))
        {
            Intracommunicator comm = Communicator.world;

            if (comm.Rank == 0)
            {
                // Generate random matrices
                int rowsA = 1000;
                int colsA = 1000;
                int colsB = 1000;

                double[,] matrixA = GenerateRandomMatrix(rowsA, colsA);
                double[,] matrixB = GenerateRandomMatrix(colsA, colsB);

                // Perform serial matrix multiplication
                Console.WriteLine("Performing serial matrix multiplication...");
                double[,] serialResult = MultiplyMatricesSerial(matrixA, matrixB);
                Console.WriteLine("Serial matrix multiplication completed.");

                // Perform parallel matrix multiplication
                Console.WriteLine("Performing parallel matrix multiplication...");
                double[,] parallelResult = MultiplyMatricesParallel(matrixA, matrixB, comm);
                Console.WriteLine("Parallel matrix multiplication completed.");

                // Compare the results with tolerance
                double tolerance = 6;
                bool equal = CompareMatrices(serialResult, parallelResult, tolerance);
                Console.WriteLine("Serial and parallel results are equal: " + equal);
            }
            else
            {
                MultiplyMatricesParallel(null, null, comm);
            }
        }
    }

    static double[,] MultiplyMatricesSerial(double[,] matrixA, double[,] matrixB)
    {
        int rowsA = matrixA.GetLength(0);
        int colsA = matrixA.GetLength(1);
        int colsB = matrixB.GetLength(1);

        double[,] result = new double[rowsA, colsB];

        for (int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < colsB; j++)
            {
                double sum = 0.0;
                for (int k = 0; k < colsA; k++)
                {
                    sum += matrixA[i, k] * matrixB[k, j];
                }
                result[i, j] = sum;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    static double[,] MultiplyMatricesParallel(double[,] matrixA, double[,] matrixB, Intracommunicator comm)
    {
        int rowsA = matrixA.GetLength(0);
        int colsA = matrixA.GetLength(1);
        int colsB = matrixB.GetLength(1);

        int blockSize = rowsA / comm.Size;
        int remainder = rowsA % comm.Size;

        int startRow = comm.Rank * blockSize;
        int endRow = startRow + blockSize;

        if (comm.Rank == comm.Size - 1)
        {
            endRow += remainder;
        }

        double[,] localMatrixA = new double[blockSize + remainder, colsA];
        double[,] localResult = new double[blockSize + remainder, colsB];

        if (comm.Rank == 0)
        {
            // Scatter matrixA to all processes
            for (int i = 1; i < comm.Size; i++)
            {
                int startIndex = i * blockSize;
                int count = (i == comm.Size - 1) ? blockSize + remainder : blockSize;
                double[,] sendBuffer = new double[count, colsA];
                Array.Copy(matrixA, startIndex * colsA, sendBuffer, 0, count * colsA);
                comm.Send(sendBuffer, i, 0);
            }

            Array.Copy(matrixA, 0, localMatrixA, 0, (blockSize + remainder) * colsA);
        }
        else
        {
            comm.Receive<double[,]>(0, 0, out localMatrixA);
        }

        // Transpose localMatrixA
        double[,] transposedLocalMatrix = TransposeMatrix(localMatrixA);

        // Perform matrix multiplication
        for (int i = startRow; i < endRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < colsB; j++)
            {
                double sum = 0.0;
                for (int k = 0; k < colsA; k++)
                {
                    sum += transposedLocalMatrix[i - startRow, k] * matrixB[k, j];
                }
                localResult[i - startRow, j] = sum;
            }
        }

        // Gather local results from all processes
        comm.Gather(localResult, 0);

        if (comm.Rank == 0)
        {
            // Concatenate and return the final result
            double[,] result = new double[rowsA, colsB];

            int index = 0;
            Array.Copy(localResult, 0, result, index, (blockSize + remainder) * colsB);

            for (int i = 1; i < comm.Size; i++)
            {
                index += blockSize;
                int count = (i == comm.Size - 1) ? blockSize + remainder : blockSize;
                comm.Receive(i, 0, out double[,] receivedResult);
                Array.Copy(receivedResult, 0, result, index, count * colsB);
            }

            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }

    static double[,] TransposeMatrix(double[,] matrix)
    {
        int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);

        double[,] transposedMatrix = new double[cols, rows];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                transposedMatrix[j, i] = matrix[i, j];
            }
        }

        return transposedMatrix;
    }

    static double[,] GenerateRandomMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        double[,] matrix = new double[rows, cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = random.NextDouble();
            }
        }

        return matrix;
    }

    static bool CompareMatrices(double[,] matrixA, double[,] matrixB, double tolerance)
    {
        int rows = matrixA.GetLength(0);
        int cols = matrixA.GetLength(1);

        if (rows != matrixB.GetLength(0) || cols != matrixB.GetLength(1))
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(matrixA[i, j] - matrixB[i, j]) > tolerance)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The are two methods to calculate the matrix product: one using serial algorithm and another one using parallel version.
but the methods are returning different Matrices result. can anyone help me

Comment: Different how? Can you do a 2x2 matrix on 2 processes and show correct & wrong output?